# Figma SVG not rendering with package flutter_svg

Tags: flutter, svg

I'm exporting svg file from figma, flutter have errors:

```
Failed to find definition for url(#pattern0)
Failed to find definition for url(#pattern1)
```

Full text of error:

The following assertion was thrown while parsing AssetBundlePictureKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#41f97(), name: "assets/images/select-image.svg", colorFilter: null, theme: SvgTheme(currentColor: Color(0xff000000), fontSize: 14.0, xHeight: 7.0)) in _getDefinitionPaint:
Failed to find definition for url(#pattern1)

This library only supports  and xlink:href references that are defined ahead of their references.

This error can be caused when the desired definition is defined after the element referring to it (e.g. at the end of the file), or defined in another file.

This error is treated as non-fatal, but your SVG file will likely not render as intended

My svg filу

```
<svg width="26" height="27" viewBox="0 0 26 27" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
    <image id="image0_133_96" width="100" height="100" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
    <pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
        <use xlink:href="#image0_133_96" transform="translate(-0.0142405) scale(0.0102848 0.01)"/>
    </pattern>
    <pattern id="pattern1" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
        <use xlink:href="#image0_133_96" transform="translate(-0.0142405) scale(0.0102848 0.01)"/>
    </pattern>
</defs>
<mask id="mask0_133_96" style="mask-type:alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="26" height="27">
    <rect y="0.333344" width="25.28" height="26" fill="url(#pattern0)"/>
</mask>
<g mask="url(#mask0_133_96)">
    <rect y="0.333344" width="25.28" height="26" fill="url(#pattern1)"/>
    <rect y="0.333344" width="25.28" height="26" fill="#9A9EAA"/>
</g>
```

Where is my error?

Comment: you are adding link of image inside the svg flutter_svg doesn't sport many think's including (gradient,url...etc.). you need to remove the url of the image from the svg file to make it work.

Comment: I tried to read your svg, its says its not a valid svg

Comment: You are missing the closing `</svg>` tag.

Comment: If remove  link then svg not show, I not right ?

Comment: Close tag </svg> is have

Answer (score -1):

I solved my problem, I converted image from figma to png to svg

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).